# How to handle UI components in subview

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, subview

In my android app, I have an activity where there is a spinner at the top, and a layout below it. So, my layout xml file consists of the spinner and LinearLayout. I am able to change the layout when I select different options in the spinner dropdown. In one of the layouts I have another spinner, and, even though I set its adapter to fill up with the contents of an ArrayList (which I checked in debug; it is non-empty), the options do not show up in the spinner.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_task);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
        subjects = bundle.getStringArrayList("subjects");

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.newtask_layoutbelow);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layout.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_homework, null));

        taskspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.newtask_taskspinner);
        taskspinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tasks));

        taskspinner
        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int position = taskspinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                layout.removeAllViews();
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    layout.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_homework, null));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    layout.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_study, null));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    layout.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_project, null));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    layout.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_subject, null));
                    break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });



        name = (EditText)  layout.findViewById(R.id.new_homework_name);
        subjectspinner = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.new_homework_subjectspinner);
        date = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.new_homework_selectdate);
        Log.e("arr",subjects.toString());
        subjectspinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subjects));

        create = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.new_homework_create_button);

        subjectspinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int position = subjectspinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                        subject = subjects.get(position);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to do something like `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the 2nd spinner/adapter _after_ is is displayed?

Comment: And yes, always post your relevant code. Check [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: I added the code. Sorry about that!

Comment: @csmckelvey I'm not sure how I would do that since I'm doing this in my onCreate method since this is the first subview I want to show.

Comment: @csmckelvey You seem to know this well. I am having the same issue. I have several LinearLayouts and I am switching them. However, I am unable to get the Spinner (which is in each of the LinearLayouts) to work. Like him, I am doing `foospinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, bararray));`. I think it has something to do with the `this` argument there, but I am not sure what the context is. I think it is the problem because it is not longer just a view in the activity, but it is a subview in the linearlayout. Do I just pass the liner layout?

Comment: @Golddove The first argument to your `ArrayAdapter` constructor is a context so it depends upon where you doing this assignment. I would need code to tell you for sure. Check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) for `ArrayAdapter` or post a question with your code.

Comment: @csmckelvey My surrounding code is quite similar to @epsilondelta's. He/she also has the code `subjectspinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subjects));` . Is that the correct context for his situation. I do not want to ask the question as I am afraid it may be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Golddove _Quite_ similar and _exactly_ similar makes a *huge* difference. I really have to see your code. If your question is marked as duplicate that means your solution is already out there :)

Comment: @csmckelvey Do you have any ideas on why the spinner isn't working?

Comment: @epsilondelta ATM, no. I've marked this question so I can come back later and take all the code and try it out myself with eclipse. I was trying to do it "in my head" and got nothing so I will try to work something out by trial and error a bit later when I have some time.